# Is possible to append a key value to an ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to have an object that has an associated value added to it.

This is what I am attempting to do:

```
@users = @search.results

@user_results = []

@users.each do |user|
  @user_results = @user_results.push user << {photo_url: UsersPhoto.find_by_user_id(user.id).image_name}
end
```

I'm getting:

NoMethodError (undefined method `<<' for #):

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what associations are for. You should just add an association to your `User` for the `UsersPhoto` you're trying to find, and use `@user.users_photo.image_name`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :users_photo
end
```

Failing that, add a `photo_url` method to your `User` model, which wraps up the `UsersPhoto.find...`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def photo_url
    UsersPhoto.find_by_user_id(id).image_name
  end
end
```

Failing *that*, you can do what you're trying to do, but you'll need to add a `attr_accessor :photo_url` to your `User` model, and your syntax is all wrong:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :photo_url
end

@users.each do |user|
  user.photo_url = UsersPhoto.find_by_user_id(user.id).image_name
end
```

Comment: ... Append *what*? I have no idea which solution you used, but *none* of them involved "appending" anything to the user object. All three solutions add the property to the user object already.

Comment: OK, forgive my ignorance. I am using the photo_url method. When I puts the user object to the console I don't see a photo_url in the object. I should, shouldn't I?

Comment: No. If you've defined a method called `photo_url`, then it's a method, and not an attribute on the object. Try `user.photo_url`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `.pluck` method?

```
@users = @search.results

@user_results = UsersPhoto.where(user_id: @users.pluck(:id) ).select(:image_name)
```

To explain, at least from what I am understanding, you want an array of image_names for the results @users. So just get their ids, find those UsersPhotos that match those ids and just get the image_name column